# Merge statement in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I came across this statement in a Intro to Cypher video:

[image]

Ignoring the last `MERGE` statement, does the `MERGE` essentially do an `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY` ? For example:

```
MERGE (a:Person {name: "Ann"})
ON CREATE SET a.twitter = "@ann"
```

Would correspond to:

```
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES ("Ann")
ON DUPLICATE KEY SET twitter = "@ann"
```

And by extension, if there is a `MERGE` on a node that doesn't already exist does it act as if it is a `CREATE` keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is what MERGE does. Note that it is not limited to just key fields. It takes into account all fields you provide in the MERGE clause. See also https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/

Comment: Thanks -- what do you mean by "key fields" ?

Comment: If you do MERGE (c:Person {name:’Tom’, gender:’male’})  neo4j will only re-ise an existing node that when both properties match, regardless of whether there is a unique constraint.